# Double integral $\iint f(x,y)$ when $f(x,y)=g(x)+h(y)$.

Tags: multiple-integral

> If I have a function $f(x,y)$ that can be written as $g(x)+h(y)$
>   can I say that
>   $$\int_a^b \int_a^{b} f(x,y) \,dx\,dy =   \int_a^b g(x) \,dx
> + \int_a^b h(y) \,dy$$

So for Example,  $\int_0^1 \int_0^{1} (x + y) \,dx\,dy$ =  $\int_0^1 x \,dx$
+ $\int_0^1  \,y dy $?
When I tried to calculate the values I found put that they don't match. I just want to know why it is wrong.

Comment: no... $\int \int \ f(x)+f(y) \ dxdy =\int \int \ f(x) \ dxdy +\int \int \ f(y) \ dxdy $ which, with your bounds, is the same as $2(b-a)\int  \ f(x) dx$

Answer (score 0):

You might accidentally get away this approach depending on the function and the limits of integration but in general that is not how you would do it. See here for a list of examples.

http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/IteratedIntegrals.aspx

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_a^{a+1} \int_b^{b+1} f(x + y) \,dx\,dy 
&=& 
\int_a^{a+1} \int_b^{b+1}  g(x)  \,dx\,dy+\int_a^{a+1} \int_b^{b+1}  h(y) \,dx\,dy \\
&=& \int_a^{a+1}\,dy\int_b^{b+1}  g(x)  \,dx +\int_b^{b+1}\,dx\int_a^{a+1}  h(y) \,dy \\
&=& \int_b^{b+1}  g(x)  \,dx +\int_a^{a+1}  h(y) \,dy
\end{eqnarray}